# How to find closest answer for given input using machine learning algorithms

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics

I have a problem which I will explain down below but I didn't decide which popular machine algorithm (kmeans , KNN etc.) is better for this problem.

So, here is my problem :

Think each input as an answer. Each question has 5 options(A,B,C,D,E) and one of them is correct.

Let's assume correct answers for specific test is : `A B B D C`

And the given 2 different input is : `A C B D C` and `B C B D C`. First one only have one incorrect answer which is second question. Second one is 2 incorrect answers.

What I'm trying to achive is find the closest answer based on correct answers. In this specific case, it's `A C B D C` because it has only one incorrect answer.

**So, I need to filter answers from the most correct to the most incorrect.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't get it. You just have to count the number of correct answers. If this number is equal for two inputs, these inputs are equally good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the "Levenshtein distance (fast-levenshtein)" based on strings.
What it does, it is a string metric for measuring the edit distance between two sequences. Or in other words, it tells you how many characters you've to change to get your other word.

```
'''
example:
"hello" - "hallo" : 1
"hello" - "helpp" : 2
"hello" - "welp"  : 3 (change 2 letters and remove 1 letter)
"hello" - "yellow": 2 (change 1 letter and add 1 letter)
 etc...
'''

import editdistance

def minimum_edit_distance(answer, answers):

    answ = []

    for a in answers:
        answ.append(editdistance.eval(answer.lower(), a.lower()))

    return answ

minimum_edit_distance("hello", ["hallo", "helpp", "welp", "yellow", "hello"])


# Result : [1, 2, 3, 2, 0]

# OR

minimum_edit_distance("ABBDC", ["ACBDC", "BCBDC", "ABBCD", "AABDC", "CCCCC"])
# Result : [1, 2, 2, 1, 4]
```

But yeah: you can also loop over the answer and check and count how many things are wrong ....